# Change "Regular price" text in WooCommerce admin product pages settings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, product

I have added 3 additional custom-fields in the prices section of woocommerce product edit pages settings. I would like to replace "Regular Price" by "List price" instead.

How can I change "Regular price" text label in Woocommerce admin product edit page settings? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2020 Update optimization** *(works for admin new product and on WooCommerce 4+ too)*

Using a custom function hooked in WordPress **"`gettext`"** filter hook, you will be able to replace in admin product edit and new product pages *(backend)* the text "**Regular price**" by "**List price**":

```
add_filter('gettext', 'change_backend_product_regular_price', 100, 3 );
function change_backend_product_regular_price( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if ( is_admin() && in_array( $pagenow, ['post.php', 'post-new.php'] )
    && 'product' === $post_type && 'Regular price' === $text  && 'woocommerce' === $domain )
    {
        $translated_text =  __( 'List price', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working with the new WooCommerce 4.
I have changed the IF statement to:
'woocommerce' === $domain && 'post-new.php' === $pagenow && 'product' === get_post_type( $_GET['post'] ) && 'Regular price' === $text

Comment: I have updated and optimize my code, and also enable the code for admin new product (which was not the case in this thread)… Try it it should work on all WooCommerce versions since at least 2.4…

Comment: Working! :) Thank you